# What is purpose of echo statement in the following php code?

Tags: php, html

I am new to PHP. I found the following code snippet in a tutorial while trying to learn radio button. The echo statement never gets executed( I do not see checked statement printed ever). What is the purpose of this echo statement?

```
<input type="radio" name="gender" <?php if (isset($gender) && $gender=="female") echo "checked";?>  value="female">Female
<input type="radio" name="gender" <?php if (isset($gender) && $gender=="male")  echo "checked";?>value="male">Male
```

Comment: it means that it will give a `checked` attribute to the radio button element if the if condition is correct.

Answer (score 1):

In this scenario `if` condition will compare value of `$gender`. When value matches then echo will print the `"checked"` attribute inside the radio in html. So the radio button will be appear checked.

You can see it by view source.